# appending lists to lists with <<- (global assignment) in browser()

Tags: r

I have a number of lists that I'm trying to assign globally, since I want them to be usable as long as R is open.
Unfortunately, I can't seem to test the behavior as it happens in my code because it is different in browser mode vs regular console.

here's the program I'll use to go into browser mode in this example

```
browsefunct<-function()
{
  browser()
  browser()
}

browsefunct()

Browse[1]> smallList <- list(1)
Browse[1]> smallList
[[1]]
[1] 1
Browse[1]> smallList <<- c(smallList,list(smallList)) #does nothing?
Browse[1]> smallList
[[1]]
[1] 1
Browse[1]> smallList <- c(smallList,list(smallList))
Browse[1]> smallList
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1
```

but yet

```
> smallList<-list(1)
> smallList <<- c(smallList,list(smallList)) #now works
> smallList
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1
```

Is this a bug in R itself?

Comment: Before suggesting bugs, especially when mucking with things like `<<-`, for which there are lots of warnings not to use unless you really know what you're doing, you should take the time to read the R-manuals and the wonderful  R-inferno (by Patrick Burns)

Comment: I read the R inferno. I'm trying to use global assignments because I want to load files into R only once ever. These variables I'm adjusting here are to keep track of those files I'm loading

Comment: Well, you can't load "only once ever" since that depends on properly maintaining your `.Rdata` file, or whatever you load at startup.

Comment: By "ever", I meant "after loading R and running it once" not literally ever, come on. I'm reading data from a file to store data into R that may be used across multiple runs of the program. Clearly, this makes sense to do globally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment inside your `browser()` is not the global environment but is instead the local environment of the function `browserfunc()`. So what you're doing is creating a local variable, then assigning something to a global variable and then looking at the local variable and wondering why it hasn't changed.

To see the value of the global variable after your assignment, do `get('smallList', env = .GlobalEnv)`.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware that <<- didn't assign both the global and local variables